# Applications Wedderburn's Little Theorem

Tags: ring-theory

I've been asked to give a short presentation of Wedderburn's Theorem that every finite domain is a field.

However, the proof itself is quite short so I thought to add some applications (since this theorem doesn't lend itself to giving many examples beyond "here is a finite domain, its a field!"). What are some interesting applications of this theorem?

Comment: It is worth explicitly emphasizing that [Wedderburn's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn's_little_theorem) concerns not necessarily commutative domains and fields, since many authors restrict those terms to the commutative case.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't say anything about application of Wedderburn's Theorem. But of course you should mention about consequences of this theorem regarding the structure of finite subgroups. Hopefully, it will be useful [A first course in noncommutative rings](http://books.google.com/books?id=f15FyZuZ3-4C&pg=PA214&dq=Wedderburn's+little+theorem&hl=en&ei=iJLWTqfBJ5Gg-waPz9XDCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CDgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=Wedderburn's%20little%20theorem&f=false)

Comment: It might be too obvious but it's used to prove that $Z_p$ is a field and that in turn is used to show that the characteristic of an integral domain is $0$ or prime...

Comment: @Matt that seems backwards.  Forgive me if I'm wrong, but the fact $Z/pZ$ is a field follows from basic number theory (every nonzero element is a unit, and the multiplicative group is commutative).

Comment: @Matt, further, you can show any finite integral domain is a field without Wedderburn (see Dummit&Foote page 228).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warning: In this answer, I'll comment about things a lot of MSE users know much better than I. I hope they'll correct and/or complete this answer.

In André Weil's book [Basic Number Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=CsGqSgAACAAJ&dq=intitle%3abasic+intitle%3anumber+intitle%3atheory&hl=en&ei=KvTYTtffKsjvsgaJ16HDCw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA).

Wedderburn's Little Theorem is used in an essential way to compute the Brauer group of a local field.

The use of WLT is at the same time conspicuous and hidden.

It is conspicuous because WLT is Theorem 1 of Chapter 1, and is stated on top of page 1.

It is hidden because WLT is never (as far as I can see) referred to explicitly in the sequel.

But if one looks closely, one sees that it is implicitly used a lot of times.

The first time is in Corollary 1 to Theorem 2 page 2.

[In this post, division rings will be called "fields", that is "not necessarily commutative fields", to stick to Weil's terminology.]

WLT is tacitly used to conclude that the residue field of a (not necessarily commutative) non-archimedian local field is a finite **commutative** field.

This enables Weil to describe in a very precise way the structure of such a (not necessarily commutative) non-archimedian local field, viewed as a division algebra over its center: see Proposition 5 page 20.

This Proposition is the culminating point of Chapter 1, and then it is used in a crucial way in:

- the comment following Definition 6 page 184,
- the proof of Theorem 1 page 222,
- the proof of Corollary 1 page 223.

A particularly important excerpt is the paragraph just before Theorem 2 page 224. Here is a part of this paragraph:

> As we identify the Brauer group $B(K)$ with the group $H(K)$ considered in theorem 1 and its corollaries, we may consider the mapping $\eta$ defined in corollary 2 of th. 1 as an isomorphism of $B(K)$ onto the group of roots of $1$ in $\mathbb C$; ...